# Why does the nuclear charge remain the same in Moseley's law?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, x-rays

So Today I was taught about the Moseley's law and its relation with Bohr's formula :

$$\frac{hc}{\lambda} =  R \left(\frac{(Z-\sigma)^2}{n^2}-\frac{(Z-\sigma)^2}{m^2}\right)$$

My understanding is that in $(Z-\sigma)$, Z is the number of protons and $\sigma$
 is related to (but not exactly) the number of electrons that is in lower shells.

So my question is that if the electron jumps to a lower level, how could value of $\sigma$ not change as stated in the Moseley's formula?

For example, let's say that an electron in L shell is knocked out. Then one electron jumps from M shell to L shell to fill the hole, the electrons under the jumping electron will change from 9 to 2. Therefore, the value of $\sigma$ should at least change and not remain constant, right?
However my professor taught me that in the example that I just mentioned, the value of $\sigma$ would remain as 9 (theoretically). How is that possible?

Comment: There is a bit about this from the Bohr prerspective in the [Wikipedia article Moseley's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley%27s_law).

Answer (score 2):

The particular formulation of [Moseley's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley's_law) is a mashup with the [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula)

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} =  RZ^2\left( \frac{1}{n_1^2}-\frac{1}{n_2^2} \right)$$

and the relationship becomes clearer if you write it as:

$$\frac{hc}{\lambda} =  R(Z-\sigma)^2 \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$

It would probably be even better to write the formula as

$$\frac{hc}{\lambda} =  Rk_{nm}(Z-\sigma)^2 \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$

where $k_{nm}$ represents a correction factor for the particular line such as $K_{\alpha1}$, or $K_{\beta1}$, etc. Moseley's law was an attempt to explain how the energy/wavelength of a particular x-ray line varied as a function of atomic number, not how all the lines in a particular atom varied.

So all in all you're right. The energy difference between the two orbitals would be dependent on the shielding in both orbitals. See for example [Slater's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules) on shielding.

Comment: I still don't get it. Rydberg formula is used for atoms that have a similar structure to hydrogen (only 1 electron). Therefore it makes sense that Z is squared as the electron is pulled by the same amount of charges (Z) no matter the level. But in Moseley's law, it applies to atoms with more electrons. Due to the shielding effect, the sigma value should be different for different level of the electron. So how is the (Z-sigma) squared in the Moseley's law?

Comment: Added more detail to the answer. Hopefully that helps. // User Farcher made an excellent suggestion to read the Wikipedia article on Mosely's Law.

Comment: Mathjax hint : If you use `\left(` and `\right)` for brackets they will be displayed at a larger size to match the contents of the brackets.

Comment: @MaxW So my understanding now is that the Moseley's law is empirical. The $\sigma$ value comes from the experiment results. It can only be used to describe certain de-excitation of atoms. The part I am confused about is that my professor said the $\sigma$ value in Moseley's law theoretically should be the no. of electrons under the jumping electron. Just like the example I gave in the post. Is he correct?

Comment: @boboboy131 - Yes, Moseley's law is empirical, though it mimics a form of the Rydberg formula which has a much stronger theoretical foundation. In the formula I showed I think of $\sigma$ more or less as being the shielding of the most bound electron. So for the $K_{\alpha}$ lines $\sigma$ would be, more or less, for the 1s electrons - like from Salter's rules. Not sure what a "best fit" would be for what I have as $k_{nm}$ and $\sigma$ over all the $K_{\alpha1}$ lines for example.

Comment: Think of my point about $\sigma$ for the $K_{\alpha}$ being for the 1s electrons this way. Instead of thinking of the electron dropping into a "hole," think of the 1s electron being excited up to a hole in the n=2 shell.

Comment: @MaxW What is the reason behind thinking of σ as for the shielding of the most bound electron?

Comment: Think of the "hole" in the excited atom as a perturbation of Slater's rules. The further from the nucleus the hole is, the less the perturbation on the inner electrons. So  as a percentage deviation, the $K_{\beta}$ lines will be closer to the approximation given by the formula than the $K_{\alpha}$ lines.

Comment: @MaxW Sorry for the countless questions but I still don't quite get what you mean. If this hole is outside the interested electrons, then there shouldn't be any effect on it according to the Slater's rules? Is there any website/link/wikipedia page that will help me understand more about this "hole" acting as a perturbation of Slater's rules? My major isn't about physics and I feel like my professor merely touched the very surface of this topic.

Comment: The $K_{\alpha 1}$ xray is the difference between the K-edge and the $L_{III}$  edge. Essentially what I am trying to say is that you'd get a better fit to the data if you computed each edge separately. Thus you'd have *four* constants to fit not *two*. $$\text{K-edge} = \dfrac{Rk_k(Z - \sigma_1)^2}{1^2}$$ $$L_{III}\text{-edge} = \dfrac{Rk_{LIII}(Z - \sigma_2)^2}{2^2}$$ Slater's rules don't cover "holes" in the inner electrons.